# MessageBox Description has only 1 letter

Tags: c++, messagebox, reinterpret-cast, lpstr, lpwstr

```
std::string Window::Exception::TranslateErrorCode(HRESULT hr) noexcept
{
    char* pMsgBuf = nullptr;
    DWORD nMsgLen = FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        nullptr,
        hr,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&pMsgBuf),
        0,
        nullptr
    );
    if (nMsgLen == 0)
    {
        return "Unidentified error code";
    }
    std::string errorString = pMsgBuf;
    LocalFree(pMsgBuf);
    return errorString;
}
```

[image: msgbox]

This is the code that returns the description string, however the string on the description is only 1 letter long, i think that the problem is that pMsgBuf that is a LPWSTR, but i don't know how to setup reinterpret_cast with LPSTR, cause if i put LPSTR it gives me an error:
"Argument of type 'LPSTR' is incompatible with parameter of type 'LPWSTR'"

Comment: If your project is using wide strings, then use wide strings everywhere. As a quick hack, you can instead use `FormatMessageA` if you want to use single-byte strings.

Comment: Just change `pMsgBuf` from `char *` to `wchar_t *` and `std::string` to `std::wstring`.

Comment: Showing only the first character typically means you've created a wide string, but you're trying to display it as a narrow string.

Comment: ***but i don't know how to setup reinterpret_cast with LPSTR*** When you have to cast a  c-string type you are probably doing something wrong.  I say that because the cast does nothing to the data. It just tells the compiler to "shut up I know what I am doing"

Comment: This is similar to [this question that you asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77876113/how-to-properly-convert-char-to-wchar-t).  As stated in the comments there, the Windows API functions that take character pointers are divided into two groups, `A` and `W`.  As noted, you should have used `FormatMessageA` if you know you are going to use non-wide strings.  Also, you should never cast string types without knowing exactly what you are doing.  Instead, you either call the functions that accept the right string types, or use the right string types for the function you're calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's 2024 and using ANSI strings in modern applications is inexcusable. You should set your project to UNICODE and use wide strings.

```
std::wstring Window::Exception::TranslateErrorCode(HRESULT hr) noexcept
{
    LPWSTR pBuffer = nullptr;

    DWORD Result = FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                      FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                      FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                      nullptr,
                      hr,
                      MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                      reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&pBuffer),
                      0,
                      nullptr);
    if (Result == 0) {
        return L"Unidentified error code";
    }

    std::wstring ErrorString = pBuffer;

    LocalFree(pBuffer);

    return ErrorString;
}
```

Second, you are passing a `HRESULT` into this code. While you can get an error message text from that you need to be aware that not all `HRESULT` codes come from `FACILITY_WIN32` and that the error message you get back [can be completely wrong](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061103-07/?p=29133).